# working on a payroll calculation program

Tags: loops, python-3.x

I'm  working on a payroll calculation and I have to get it to loop

```
while name= karen:
    name = (input("enter employees name"))
    if karen>0:
        hours=float(input("enter hours worked"))
        rate=float(input('enter hourly rate'))
        total= (hours)*(rate)+(overtimetotal)
        print (total)
        # when over time
        if hours>40:
            overtimerate=1.50
            overtimetotal= (total)* (overtimerate)
            print (overtimetotal)
```

my instructor said "There should not be an input for overtimehours. You are calculating it by taking the hours-40
You need to calculate the total as total=hours*rate+overtimetotal
You need to have a while loop to checking the name !="0"
everything in the loop block will be indented."

Im lost at what to write to start the loop.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you please edit your code so that it compiles?  Your indenting didn't come out correctly from your cut and paste, and I think you're missing some quoting.  It would also help if you precisely describe what your program is supposed to do -- inputs and outputs.  Formalizing that may also help you correct your errors.  This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To go along with the above comment, it's also unclear what `karen` is supposed to be, and why `karen>0` is a case in your code.

Comment: @JennerFelton Exactly. I suppose it's only a part of a program.